# How to remove or override files that are added to pyspark job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I added an egg file to pyspark context by using

```
sc.addPyFile('/path/to/my_file.egg')
```

However, if I made some change and rebuild my egg file. I can't add it again. Spark said that the file already exists that I can't add it again.Here is the stacktrace

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: File /tmp/spark-ddfc2b0f-2897-4fac-8cf3-d7ccee04700c/userFiles-44152f58-835a-4d9f-acd6-f841468fa2cb/my_file.egg exists and does not match contents of file:///path/to/my_file.egg
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyFile(Utils.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1409)
```

Is there a way to tell spark to override it?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. It looks like `sc.clearFiles()` was [removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17525) in version 2.

Comment: Not working for me as well. I am using Spark 1.6

Answer (score 0):

This may work depending on your use case, this is not foolproof though!

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('file_test').config("spark.files.overwrite", "true").getOrCreate()
# Adding spark.files.overwrite is actually letting Spark know that files added via sparkContext can be overwritten.
# user_file_path is where your file resides on the file system
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(user_file_path)
# change the file and add again
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(user_file_path)
```

Although this worked for the most part, I have run into issues with this approach at times. I was dynamically adding Python files to test some UDFs and I needed to automatically generate some Python methods. I ran into some issues when I used the same file to overwrite the content and add to Spark Py files, It looks like Spark does some kind of content change check before propagating to all executors and it seems to have some issues. I got around this by creating a new file every time the content changed and it worked for me as I don't care about how many files I am adding.

Answer (score 0):

```
spark._sc.addPyFiles("some_file.py")
print(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("some_file.py") # expect: /tmp/xxx/xxx/xxx1/some_file.py
spark._sc.addPyFiles("some_file.py")
print(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("some_file.py") # expect: /tmp/xxx/xxx/xxx1/some_file.py

spark._sc.addPyFiles("some_file.py")
print(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("some_file.py") 
# expect: /tmp/xxx/xxx/xxx1/some_file.py
spark._sc.stop()
spark._sc = spark.sparkContext
spark._sc.addPyFiles("some_file.py")
print(pyspark.SparkFiles.get("some_file.py") 
# expect: /tmp/xxx/xxx/xxx2/some_file.py
```

Resetting the _sc of sparkSession can re-upload files to the executor, which is faster than restarting SparkSession

Comment: spark._sc = spark.sparkContext is throwing an error, "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setJobGroup'"

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could remove (or override) files that were added by means of sc.addPyiFiles() was to restart the pyspark interpreter.